# Есть ли в JS - обычная функция поиска по всему документу?

Tags: javascript

То есть предположим я знаю, что в DOM должно быть внесено изменение к примеру где то, в каком то элементе, в каком то div ... должна появится "фраза" - "Hello World" - это может быть текст, value или еще что то, я этого не знаю.

И просто хочу найти эту фразу - "Hello World". Есть какой нибудь метод .find() - по всему документу?

Comment: Есть [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)..

Comment: Допустим есть, вы что хотите дольше с этим делать? Просто удостовериться или надо будет менять его в DOM-е?

Comment: @EzioMercer, только удостовериться, что оно присутствует в DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например с помощью [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```js
console.log(document.body.innerHTML.indexOf('Hello world') !== -1)
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а есть ли такая же функция, но которую можно применять к Element ? Ну что то типа такого: let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("Textinput-Control")[0]; elem .indexOf("555"); ?

Comment: @Staxcelrom У любого элемента есть `innerHTML`

Comment: а существует аналог innerHTML , который преобразовывает в текст - не только дочерние узлы элемента, но и весь элемент ?

Comment: @Staxcelrom `outerHTML`